# Multiplicative inverse of $4x+3$ in the ring $ \mathbb Z_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

> How to find the multiplicative inverse of $4x+3$ in the ring $ \mathbb Z_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$?

I understand that any element belonging to the ring $ \mathbb Z_{11}[x]/(x^2+1)$ is of the form $ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb Z_{11}$. How to proceed?

Comment: @Tom Solve the linear system modulo $\;11\;$ , for example (all the time arithmetic modulo $11$): $$3a+4b=0\implies 3a=-4b=7b\implies a=3^{-1}\cdot7b=28b=6b$$ and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $x^2=-1$, thus
$$
\frac1{4x+3}=\frac{4x-3}{(4x+3)(4x-3)}=\frac{3-4x}3=1+6x
$$
(I used that $4=3^{-1}\bmod 11$).

Comment: It’s exactly what you did in high school to find the reciprocal of $3+4i$

Comment: @Mori sir how -4/3 will be ? sir please explain

Comment: @Gopinath: I explained it in the text: $4$ and $3$ are each other inverses modulo $11$.

Comment: @AndreaMori yeah sir Just now I realized Thank you sir and two minutes back I posted one question can you please answer it

Answer (score 2):

Use the *Euclidean algorithm* in $\mathbf Z/11\mathbf Z$ to obtain a *Bézout's relation* between $x^2+1$ and $4x+3$:

\begin{alignat}{6}
&3x+6 \\
&———&~\\
4x+3\;\Bigl(\;&\phantom{-}x^2\phantom{{}+2x}{}+1\\
&{-x^2}+2x&\\
&~~~~~————&~\\
&~~~\phantom{——}2x+1 \\
&~~~\phantom{—}-2x+1 \\
&~~~~~~\phantom{—}———&~\\
&~~~~~~~\phantom{———}5&
\end{alignat}

Thus we have
\begin{align}x^2+1=(3x+6)(4x+3)+5&\iff(3x+6)(4x+3)\equiv-5\pmod {x^2+1}\\
&\iff 2(3x+6)(4x+3)\equiv 1\pmod{x^2+1},
\end{align}
and the inverse is
$$(4x+3)^{-1}=2(3x+6)=6x+1.$$

Comment: sir how did you get 3x+6 ?

Comment: @Gopinath; Just like in an ordinary Euclidean division in $\mathbf Q[x]$, except that computations happen modulo $11$, so the inverse of $4$, for instance, is $3$. Does this make it clearer?